# gradle: Skipping task ':test' as it has no source files and no previous output files

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco

The problem seems to have to do with the fact that the project structure is wrong. As I read on another SO thread, the java project structure should follow `/src/main/java/com` and `/src/test/java/com` for the tests. I triple checked and the structure is correct.

The build task do work though. The build folder is populated and the jar file is created.
I can run the tests in vs-code without issues.
There are other projects in the same workspace which runs the test task just fine.

Here's the debug log on the problematic project:

```
Task :modules:advisors:test NO-SOURCE
[...]
Skipping task ':modules:advisors:test' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
[...]
Task :modules:advisors:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
```

Here's my setup:

gradle version: 4.10.2
vs-code version: 1.47.3
vs-code java version: v0.57.0

*Update*:
I found what I did wrong when migrating from Maven to Gradle. Turns out the tests class name must end with "Test" to get picked up since I'm no longer using maven-surefire-plugin. I was instead naming them starting with "Test".

Here's the documentation for the maven-surefire-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

There is two ways to fix this:

1. Edit the names of all classes so they end with "Test"
2. Add this snippet of code in your workspace build.gradle

   ```
    test {
        include "**/Test*.class"
        include "**/*Test.class"
        include "**/*Test.class"
        include "**/*TestCase.class"
    }
   ```